# Passing Too Many Arguments to Object Method - Python

Tags: python, arguments

So I think I have an incredibly simple case but I'm utterly lost about why it won't execute.

Here's my source - this is my main.py file that I'm running by just executing 'python main.py' from the command line:

```
import player
import enemy

p1 = player.playerClass(health = 200.0, position = [1, 0, 0], damage = 30.0)
e1 = enemy.enemyClass(position = [3, 0, 0], damage = 35.0)

print("Before attacking: " + str(e1.Health))
p1.Attack(e1, p1.Damage) # Error is here
print("After attacking: " + str(e1.Health))
```

The code for the Attack method is found within the playerClass class. The enemyClass is exactly the same without the Attack() method (trying to keep everything as simple as possible)

```
import character

class playerClass(character.CharacterBaseClass): # derived class used to contain an 'Attack' method, but does not anymore

    def __init__(self, health = 100.0, position = [0, 0, 0], damage = 10.0):
        self.Health = health
        self.pos = position
        self.Damage = damage

    def Attack(self, target):
        self.CurrentTarget = target
        target.Health -= self.Damage
        self.CurrentTarget = None
```

From what I've been reading, I've applied the 'self' keyword to the class definition of Attack, and 'p1' should be being passed as such when 'p1.Attack(...)' is called, but for some reason I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Attack() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any suggestions on what I'm missing? I know there are some related questions about the same issue but those questions explain *why* 'self' is needed, which I already (sort of) get.

Comment: Apparently, your idea of the definition of `playerClass.Attack()` doesn't match reality. Are you **certain** you are looking at the right `def Attack()` and have restarted your Python script?

Comment: Also, why are you passing the player's damage to it's method via an argument? Doesn't the `self` parameter give you access to the player's attributes? `self.Damage`?

Comment: Please show more of your source code, with just these snippets it looks correct. It could be many things, of which we cannot even venture a guess without seeing everything. Likely, it would be an overloaded Attack method, one which only takes one argument (+ self, so 2 total).

Comment: Haha, yes, you are correct about the self.Damage parameter; that was an artifact left over as I originally had this Attack method in the playerClass's base class.

@Martijin, I'm not exactly sure what you're saying; are you saying that when the code executes it might be executing with perhaps an older version of the Attack() method? This is where my train of thought was going but I closed and reopened my coding environment (I'm just editing python scripts in VS Code). Is there another method of 'restarting [my] Python script' that you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up finding the solution and it has a little to do with @martijin's suggestion.

The issue was that I had compiled python files in the directory that my main.py file was run from - in turn, when python was executing, it was referring to these compiled .pyc files and not the actual script files that I was editing.

Deleting these compiled .pyc files solved my problem as it appears python is now referencing the correct .py script files.

Thanks for input everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your player.playerClass like this

```
class playerClass:
  def __init__ (self, health, position, damage):
    self.health = health
    self.position = position
    self.damage = damage
  def Attack(self, target, damage):
    self.CurrentTarget = target
    target.Health -= damage
    self.CurrentTarget = None
```

### What does `self` mean?

`self` is basically an argument that python passed automatically to the method of a initialized class. The value of self is the equal to that of the class instance. So in your case, in the method `Attake ()`, `self` is equal to `p1`. By running `self.CurrentTarget = target` you are doing the same thing as `p1.CurrentTarget = target`

Comment: I'm aware of including the 'self' keyword in the function definition for the class; I had that implemented already. Hence why I'm confused because to the best of my (albeit very limited) knowledge, this is exactly what is required to accomplish what I want :/